# Table tbody limits itself to 1 column's width

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a script generating a table from a database (to display elections results).
I want some parts (for the primaries) to be collapsed (and only opened when clicking on a corresponding button).

**Here is a part of the javascript code I'm using:**

```js
// Previous candidates in the loop
row +=
  '<tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;" onclick="toggler(this.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling);">';
row += PartyName(candidate.getAttribute("party")) + " primaries ▼"; // The display button
row += "</td></tr>";
row += '<tbody class="collapsible" style="display:block;">';
// Code running through the primaries candidates to display them
row += "</tbody>";
// Next candidates in the loop
```

**The toggler function:**

```js
function toggler(item) {
  if (item.style.display == "none") {
    item.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    item.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**Here is what the table currently looks like:**
[image: Everything in the tbody only fits in the wideness of 1 column]
The images on the left are not a problem (I just need to add them to the file). The problem, as you see, is that the tbody only fits in the width of 1 column. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose defining `display: block` for a table element will make the typical table properties obsolete, so I guess you should use `height: 0` versus `height: auto` instead of `display: block/none`, also adding `overflow-y: hidden` to cut off the display when height is zero.

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work, but I found that `display: vertical-row-group` was actually the solution. Thank you anyway!